# Codeigniter Database Selection On Login Screen

Tags: codeigniter

Hi I tried Login screen Username password and one more field year

Year is Database name Selection

For example i have 2015_db,2016_db,2017_db
Based on login screen selection field of Year

```
<?php echo form_open('login',$attributes); ?>

    <label for="ddlLanguage">English</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ddlLanguage" id="ddlLanguage" value="eng" checked="checked"> 
    <label for="ddlLanguage">Arabic</label>
    <input type="radio" name="ddlLanguage" id="radio2" value="ar"> 

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <input type="text" name="txtUsername" value="<?= $this->vAdmin;?>" class="usernameLogin" />

    <input type="password" name="txtPassword" value="<?= $this->vPass;?>" class="usernameLogin" />

    <select name="year" id="year" > 
        <option value="2015">--2015--</option>
        <option value="2015">--2016--</option>
    </select>

    <label class="label" for="chkSave" > REMEMBERME </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkSave" value="1" /> 

    <a href="<?php echo base_url('forgotpassword/showlist');?>" class="forgot">FORGOTPASSWORD?</a>

    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="LOGIN" class="login">

</form>
```

Please Help me how to assign the database name in controller and model in dynamically.

like this

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = $client_db_username; // you got this from the 'admin' database
$config['password'] = $client_db_password; // you got this from the 'admin' database
$config['database'] = $client_db_name; // you got this from the 'admin' database
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = "";
$config['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

$this->load->database($config);
```

A lot of the tables each database never change, and contain the same information.

I would like to have a main application database that contains this information, including a list of years and what there database is called. This database would then be used to select the correct year database..

Comment: Try not to use php echo for everything, only when it's data from the controller. Along with that, it's not needed to include index.php in your base url, if you setup your base url properly you could either have it removed completely or just have the `base_url()` function include that automatically.

Comment: I have edited your question so it's more readable, I also added the php short tag to echo out data. Another tip is to remove any styling you've added unless your question is styling related. This just cleans up the code for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

So at first you must have all of these databases pre-defined in the `config/database.php` file. It should look like something as follow

```
$db['db_2015'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);

$db['db_2016'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
```

);

Once you've filled all databases there you want to check your input in the controller where it's posted to.

```
 public function getPostLogin()
 {
      $this->loginModel->validateLogin($this->input->post());//This will also send the database along to the function where you could catch which database to use.
 }
```

Inside your model you could do something like this:

```
<?php class loginModel extends CI_model{

      public function validateLogin($params)
      {
           $this->load->database($params['database']);
           //After this you can run queries like always.
           return $this->db->get('users');//just an example!

      }

}
```